# MVC C# Log In Masterpage

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, master-pages

Hey,
I'm new to mvc .net. 
I have a masterpage which has a log in on it. Now i want to be able to log on from any page.
But i can't seem to get it to work. I have a AccountController with the method logon and a master page.
This is the Login on the masterpage

```
 <% using (Html.BeginForm("LogOn", "Account"))
              { %>
           <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Login foutief. probeer opnieuw.") %>
           <div id="login_panel">

                     <fieldset>

                        <div class="editor-label">
                             <%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName) %>
                        </div>

                        <div class="editor-field">
                            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName) %>
                            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName) %>
                        </div>

                        <div class="editor-label">
                            <%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password) %>
                        </div>

                        <div class="editor-field">
                            <%: Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password) %>
                            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password) %>
                        </div>

                        <div class="editor-label">
                            <%: Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe) %>
                            <%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe) %>
                        </div>

                        <p>
                        <input type="submit" value="Log On" />
                        </p>
                    </fieldset>

            </div>
            <% } %>
```

And this is the Controller

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (persoonRepos.aanmelden(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {
                FormsService.SignIn(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
                {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            }
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

When i test it, it wont go in to the accountmodel LogOn method.

Someone who can help me?

Comment: where are you setting your breakpoint when testing to see if it is getting into the LogOn method?

Comment: My breakpoint is in the logon method, it doenst go into it that's the problem. I thought with this line: Html.BeginForm("LogOn", "Account") it should do it.

Comment: have you changed anything with the routes in global.asax?

Comment: On the rendered page, what does the produced HTML form code look like?

Comment: This is the page rendered http://img189.imageshack.us/i/unledyd.png/.
I have fixed it now by loging in on a different page, but i want it like on the screen, that a user can log in on every page without having to go on an whole new page. You understant?

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do, what I meant is look at "view source" of your page in the browser....what does it say in the <form> tag?

Comment: <form action="/Account/LogOn" method="post">
is this what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you are saying, the only thing I can think of that is keeping that form from hitting the LogOn Controller Action is that the master page isn't aware of the LogOnModel and then can't pass it properly to the controller.

At the very top of your MasterPage you will have a line like this

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage" %>
```

If you have the form above embedded directly in your MasterPage, then it needs to be aware of the LogOnModel, so to make that happen make that top line look like this...

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage<YourProjectName.Models.LogOnModel>" %>
```

Of Course replace "YourProjectName" with the name of your project...Then unless there is something else we're not seeing with your setup, that LogOn function should be hit when you submit the login.

Comment: <%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage<Project_Afwezigheid.Models.LogOnModel>" %>
Nope this line was already in the code ;)